# Is there a term for $x^{1/4}$

Tags: terminology, arithmetic

The *square root* of $n$ is $n^{1/2}$

The *cube root* of $n$ is $n^{1/3}$

Is there a term for $n^{1/4}$

Or would you just say 4th root or something?

**Update:**

I'm asking if there's a term for this root, or if they're only *labeled* up to the cube (probably because the terms make an analogy to shapes, and we humans can only conceptualize up to 3 dimensions)..

Comment: There isn't a standard term other than *fourth* root.

Comment: you could try with square root of a square root, but in this way you will stuck at the next $1/5$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root) mentions the following on roots:

> A root of degree 2 is called a square root and a root of degree 3, a cube root. Roots of higher degree are referred to using ordinal numbers, as in fourth root, twentieth root, etc.

While the "tesseract root" might make sense, it is probably not a widely recognized term for the fourth root.

Answer (score 3):

Since fourth degree polynomials are called [quartic polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function) and the formula for their solution is usually called the quartic formula, I have usually heard "fourth root" or "quartic root" for $\sqrt[4]{x}=x^{1/4}$.

Answer (score 1):

In really old literature (before 1900), a fairly standard term for the 4th root is *biquadratic root*. See [this 1800-1899 google-books search for "biquadratic root"](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1800%2Ccd_max%3A1899&tbm=bks&q=%22biquadratic+root%22).

Answer (score 0):

you could say 4th root, I suppose if you want to keep the flow going you could either say:

Tesseract root? (4-d cube/square)

Comment: If you say Tesseract root no one will know what you're talking about.

Comment: Its not meant to make a serious answer haha... it just seemed the asker was curious what would the next word be?

Comment: A *Tesseract root* reminds me of that book [A Wrinkle in Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Wrinkle_in_Time)